Why is my SQLite3 BLOB value passed to an application defined function sometimes as TEXT and sometimes as BLOB
I have an SQLite extension which exports following application defined functions:

vector_from_json(input_json_text): which parses input text json and returns a blob. The implementation is here

void VectorFromJson(sqlite3_context *ctx, int argc, sqlite3_value **argv) {
  if (argc != 1) {
    std::string err = absl::StrFormat(
        "vector_from_json expects 1 argument but %d provided", argc);
    sqlite3_result_error(ctx, err.c_str(), -1);
    return;
  }

  if (sqlite3_value_type(argv[0]) != SQLITE_TEXT) {
    sqlite3_result_error(ctx, "vector_from_json expects a JSON string", -1);
    return;
  }

  std::string_view json_str(
      reinterpret_cast<const char *>(sqlite3_value_text(argv[0])),
      sqlite3_value_bytes(argv[0]));

  auto vector = vectorlite::Vector::FromJSON(json_str);
  if (!vector.ok()) {
    std::string err = absl::StrFormat("Failed to parse vector due to: %s",
                                      vector.status().message());
    sqlite3_result_error(ctx, err.c_str(), -1);
    return;
  }

  sqlite3_result_blob(ctx, vector->ToBlob().data(), vector->ToBlob().size(),
                      SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
  return;
}


vector_distance(vector_blob1, vector_blob2, distance_type_text): which calculates the distance between two vectors of type blob and then returns a double value. The source code is here

void VectorDistance(sqlite3_context *ctx, int argc, sqlite3_value **argv) {
  if (argc != 3) {
    std::string err = absl::StrFormat(
        "vector_distance expects 3 arguments but %d provided", argc);
    sqlite3_result_error(ctx, err.c_str(), -1);
    return;
  }

  if (sqlite3_value_type(argv[0]) != SQLITE_BLOB ||
      sqlite3_value_type(argv[1]) != SQLITE_BLOB) {
    sqlite3_result_error(ctx, "vectors_distance expects vectors of type blob",
                         -1);
    return;
  }

  if (sqlite3_value_type(argv[2]) != SQLITE_TEXT) {
    sqlite3_result_error(
        ctx, "vectors_distance expects space type of type text", -1);
    return;
  }

  std::string_view space_type_str(
      reinterpret_cast<const char *>(sqlite3_value_text(argv[2])),
      sqlite3_value_bytes(argv[2]));
  auto distance_type = vectorlite::ParseDistanceType(space_type_str);
  if (!distance_type.has_value()) {
    std::string err =
        absl::StrFormat("Failed to parse space type: %s", space_type_str);
    sqlite3_result_error(ctx, err.c_str(), -1);
    return;
  }

  std::string_view v1_str(
      reinterpret_cast<const char *>(sqlite3_value_text(argv[0])),
      sqlite3_value_bytes(argv[0]));

  auto v1 = vectorlite::Vector::FromBlob(v1_str);
  if (!v1.ok()) {
    std::string err = absl::StrFormat("Failed to parse 1st vector due to: %s",
                                      v1.status().message());
    sqlite3_result_error(ctx, err.c_str(), -1);
    return;
  }

  std::string_view v2_str(
      reinterpret_cast<const char *>(sqlite3_value_text(argv[1])),
      sqlite3_value_bytes(argv[1]));
  auto v2 = vectorlite::Vector::FromBlob(v2_str);
  if (!v2.ok()) {
    std::string err = absl::StrFormat("Failed to parse 2nd vector due to: %s",
                                      v2.status().message());
    sqlite3_result_error(ctx, err.c_str(), -1);
    return;
  }

  auto distance = vectorlite::Distance(*v1, *v2, *distance_type);
  if (!distance.ok()) {
    sqlite3_result_error(ctx, absl::StatusMessageAsCStr(distance.status()), -1);
    return;
  }
  sqlite3_result_double(ctx, static_cast<double>(*distance));
  return;
}

However, I can observe that vector_distance sometimes gets the return value of vector_from_json as TEXT unexpectedly.
-- load my extension
.load 'path-to-my-extension.so'

CREATE TABLE vectors (
    id PRIMARY KEY,
    vector BLOB NOT NULL
);

--insert two rows
INSERT INTO vectors (id, vector)
VALUES 
    (0, vector_from_json('[1,2,3]')),
    (1, vector_from_json('[2,3,4]'));

-- when used in top level, vector_distance works fine
select vector_distance(vector_from_json('[1,2,3]'), vector_from_json('[1,2,3]'), 'cosine')

-- however, if not used in top level, vector_distance complains about the second argument being of type TEXT instead of BLOB. Though its size is still 12 bytes(3 float32 values) as expected.
SELECT id,vector_distance(vector, vector_from_json('[2,3,4]'), 'cosine') AS distance
FROM vectors ;

DELETE FROM vectors where id = 0;
-- If there's only one row in the table, the same query runs perfectly
SELECT id,vector_distance(vector, vector_from_json('[2,3,4]'), 'cosine') AS distance FROM vectors;

My questions are:

why my SELECT query works when there's only one row in the table vectors but doesn't work when there're two
why the result of vector_from_json('[2,3,4]'), which is of type BLOB, is passed to vector_distance as TEXT when vectors table has more than one rows.


Does SELECT typeof(vector) FROM vectors say they're text or blobs?

And include the implementation of vector_from_json() in your question.

@Shawn I just tried and they are all blobs in vectors table.
